# Why are .java files (servlets) inaccessible to the client?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

In my web-app I have a servlet that acts as the index. It is bound/mapped to "index.jsp" (index.jsp *doesn't actually exist*) but it is called "Index.java". The client can go to index.jsp (which will go through the servlet) but if the client tries to go to Index.java *directly* it will say it can't find the resource. Why is this?

I know that files/folders inside of WEB-INF/META-INF aren't accessible to clients but why aren't .java files? I mean, it makes sense (because you SHOULDN'T be able to go to them directly.) but what is happening to prevent the user from gaining access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, all java classes are compiled to `.class` files (and might be placed in a jar) and placed under `WEB-INF/classes` or `WEB-INF/lib` and therefore, is unable to be accessed by public (since everything under `WEB-INF` is not publicly accessible).

Furthermore, unless you explicitly included the `.java` source codes into the war (when you build the war), you won't even find the `.java` files (in your case, the `Index.java`) in the servlet container.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Glad it helps. Consider accepting the answer if it answers/solves your problem

Comment: Of course, I just had to wait the minimum amount of time to accept an answer :]

Answer (score 1):

Java source wouldn't be accessible to clients because the code would've been compiled into `.class` files and in an area in the war/ear inaccessible to clients (either in `WEB-INF/classes` or `WEB-INF/lib`).